# vc-annotate: strip the last character of git commit id

Tags: git, vc

When editing a file managed by Git, `vc-annotate` shows the output of `git blame`. As Git usually does, revisions are identified by a short commit id.

The short commit id is abbreviated to be one character longer than in the output of every other command. This breaks workflows where I use the annotate buffer to navigate to a commit, copy the revision (which is an abbreviated commit id), and search this abbreviated commit id elsewhere (`git log --oneline`, Magit control buffer, `git rebase -i` commit list, …). I need to remove the last character from the commit id.

If I can't [convince Git itself to use the same short commit length for `git blame` as for other commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849093/use-the-same-commit-abbreviation-length-for-git-blame-as-other-commands), how can I make `vc-annotate` strip the last character of commit ids?

A quick look at the vc code doesn't reveal an obvious way to run a hook after a specific command for a specific version control system.

Comment: Of course git *might* need to show you a longer hash than it would normally do, in order to avoid collisions.  IIRC it will display a currently-unique abbreviation.  Do you know how that interacts with the behaviour you're describing?  If adding one extra char for uniquification purposes does not result in *two* extra chars in vc-annotate, then stripping the final char could occasionally leave you with a non-unique hash.

Comment: @phils Git selects a hash length for uniqueness in the repository, but then its blame command adds one only for the sake of the boundary commit (very unusually: boundary commits) which is displayed as `^1234567` instead of `12345678` so that `1234567` is unique and not just `12345678`. The chances that this would be relevant in an interactive workflow, especially in this case where I'm looking at the whole history and so a single commit is the boundary commit, are extremely remote and not worth the aggravation of the extra characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this at the Git level by creating a custom Git command `blame-1` which abbreviates commit IDs to the standard length. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849093/use-the-same-commit-abbreviation-length-for-git-blame-as-other-commands/77788346#77788346

In my Emacs init file, I use the following code to use `git blame-1` instead of `git blame` for vc-annotate.

```lisp
(defvar my-git-have-blame-1 'unknown)

(defun my-after-load-vc-git ()
  (defun my-git-have-blame-1-update ()
    (setq my-git-have-blame-1
          (and (save-match-data
                 (or
                  (executable-find "git-blame-1")
                  (let ((aliases (vc-git--run-command-string
                                  nil "config"
                                  "--get-regexp" "^alias\\.")))
                    (string-match "^alias\\.blame-1 " aliases))))
               t)))

  (defun my-git-have-blame-1 ()
    (if (eq my-git-have-blame-1 'unknown)
        (my-git-have-blame-1-update))
    my-git-have-blame-1)

  (defadvice vc-git-command
      (before vc-git-command-use-my-aliases compile activate)
    (when (and (equal "blame" (ad-get-arg 3))
               (my-git-have-blame-1))
      (ad-set-arg 3 "blame-1")))

  t)
(eval-after-load "vc-git" '(my-after-load-vc-git))
```